# Convert float to currency in Pandas before writing to Excel the right way

Tags: python, excel, pandas, currency

I have a dataframe I'm eventually writing to excel using the to_excel method.
One of the columns is represents a monetary amount.
Currently it's float, and what I'd to accomplish is to write it as currency.
**However**, it's important that excel would read the data in the column as currency, not as string (so, for example, you could perform calculations on the column).

Whatever I try, excel reads the column as string.
This is what I've tried:

```
df['Monetary_Field'] = df['Monetary_Field'].map(lambda x: '$%2.0f' % x)
df['Monetary_Field'] = df['Monetary_Field'].map(lambda x: '${:20,.0f}'.format(x))
df['Monetary_Field'] = df['Monetary_Field'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

(tried these separately of course, not one after the other).

Can you please help?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

Currency is a format in Excel, the data itself is still represented as the same numerics.

If you want to control the formatting in Excel, you can do something like this, getting access to the underlying XlsxWriter object and specifying formatting.  I based this on the linked blog post which has more explanation and examples.
http://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html

```
In [95]: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx')

In [96]: df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report')

In [97]: wb = writer.book

In [98]: ws = writer.sheets['report']

In [99]: money_fmt = wb.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0'})

In [100]: ws.set_column('B:B', 12, money_fmt)
Out[100]: 0

In [101]: writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and pointing that link. For whatever reason it won't work for me. It runs the script without fail, but the output is the same. :(

Also, any idea what the 12 refers to?
Tnx again

Comment: Make sure that 'B:B' refers to the actual column you want to format; 12 is the column width.  Pandas is using XlsxWriter to write the Excel file, which is well documented here - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/

Comment: thanks for responding. of course I made sure I'm referring to the right col :) Still nothing though :(

Comment: I have a program which I run weekly, which the columns might change. It would be great if you could attach the format to the df object and then have it applied to the excel file as you write it.